# How to get error message of each field from form object in symfony2?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I followed this tutorial http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html and I rendered my insert form perfectly but only one problem that I can't solve:

I want to show all error of each field when the form is not valid. This is example code:

```
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if (false === $form->isValid()) {
        // How to get all error message of each field ??
    }
```

This look like a very basic info but I can not find any guide to solve this problem. Hope someone can help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Accessing errors from controller**

You can access errors as array using `$form->getErrors()` in controller.

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
if (false === $form->isValid()) {
    // How to get all error message of each field ??
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($form->getErrors());
}
```

**Accessing errors from `TWIG`**

- Displays all errors in template

  `{{ form_errors(form) }}`
- Access error for specific field

  `{{ form_errors(form.username) }}`

Comment: in controller, after I getErrors, how can I get field name and it's error message?

Comment: Use `$nameErrors = $form['name']->getErrors();`
, More here https://knpuniversity.com/blog/symfony-debugging-form-errors