# Unable to display form errors in twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I have no idea to extract the errors from the below nested array. I'm wondering I should use foreach to get the error array displayed in twig?

```
"errors" => FormErrorIterator {#1191 ▼
  -form: Form {#807 ▼
    -config: FormBuilder {#796 ▶}
    -parent: Form {#747 ▼
      -config: FormBuilder {#828 ▶}
      -parent: null
      -children: OrderedHashMap {#819 ▶}
      -errors: array:1 [▼
        0 => FormError {#1185 ▼
          -message: "Your first name must be at least characters long"
          #messageTemplate: "Your first name must be at least characters long"
          #messageParameters: array:2 [▶]
          #messagePluralization: 1
          -cause: ConstraintViolation {#1196 ▶}
          -origin: Form {#807}
        }
      ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a widget for this:

```
{{ form_errors(form) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Accessing errors from **TWIG**

Displays all errors in template

```
{{ form_errors(form) }}
```

Access error for specific field

```
{{ form_errors(form.username) }}
```

Read More: [How to get error message of each field from form object in symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40712685/2689199)